# Fetch stranger's favourites with Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm experimenting with fetching a list of public likes,

eg `graph.facebook.com/[my own id]/likes` 
gives a list of books, authors etc that I've "liked".

But if I use the ID for someone I'm not connected to, although I can see on their public page they have a long list of "likes" that I can just go and look at, the graph API returns an empty list.

Is there something I'm missing about graph API permissions and public likes?

Thanks for any information you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something I'm missing about graph API permissions and public likes?

Apps are not allowed to access just *any* data, only because it might be “public” when viewed through facebook.com.

For most data, you’ll have to request the according [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from the current user of your app to access it via the API.

Comment: Thanks; in the graph explorer app I've selected 'user likes' and 'friends likes', but there doesn't seem to be anything for 'stranger's likes'....

Comment: As I said, apps are not allowed to access just any data for any given Facebook user.

Comment: I'll interpret that as "yes the programmer's interface is significantly different to the user interface". Weird but it answers my question, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also, its important to point out that 'favorites' and 'likes' are two different things. The 'favorites' are the list of apps and pages on the left when you are logged into the main facebook page. Those are different than pages you've 'liked'. Just an FYI.

[image]